# C++ mySQL lib nowhere to be found

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio, mysql-connector

I cant seemd to find any way to add the mySQL library in Visual Studio, I have tried downloading the connector, but it doesnt matter how many times I install it, the lib wont show up. I tried to find the lib anywhere else, or any other method of getting the needed files. But I just cant find anything anywhere, it al just points towards the connector page.

Getting pretty desperate here...
Willing to take the downvotes for a good answer.

Comment: Ill do anything, if i knew how to. Any tips or directions?

Comment: Did you install this: [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/8.0/en/connector-cpp-installation-binary.html#connector-cpp-installation-binary-windows](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/8.0/en/connector-cpp-installation-binary.html#connector-cpp-installation-binary-windows) if you did install the windows binary, did you choose the "Complete" install?

Comment: what do you mean by "show up"? Have you tried changing the visual studio project settings to include the install directory?

Comment: Yes, I tried all the options there.

Comment: And yes i tried to include the install directory. Nothing works.

Comment: I just tested the online installer in win10, I had it install Connector/C++ 8.0.23 and all the libs were placed here: `C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector C++ 8.0\lib64\vs14`

Comment: The download I used was the 2.4MB one here: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/

Comment: You could try searching with "everything" https://www.voidtools.com/

Comment: The installer had a log of what files it installed and where it put them if you clicked "Show Details". I still have the window open and just clicked it to see the log.

Comment: I just reiinstalled both visual studios and mySQL, I was pretty much done with it. It worked though. I still have no idea what was wrong.